# AssertTrue on isSelected() fails test case, but should pass

Tags: java, selenium

I'm a newbie at Selenium/Java.  I have two test cases where I'm asserting on radio button elements with the isSelected() method.  The first test case passes as I assert False on the element which isn't selected.  However, the second test case fails but should pass: I assert True on the element -- unspecified radio button -- which IS selected.  I can't find a logic error in what I've done.  I'm not sure whether this could be a timing issue perhaps?

```
public class RegistrationPage extends TestBase{

//Object Repository - Page Factory
@FindBy(xpath="//label[contains(text(), 'Male')]")
        WebElement maleRadioBtn;

@FindBy(xpath="//label[contains(text(), 'unspecified')]")
        WebElement unspecifiedRadioBtn;

@FindBy(name="agree")
    WebElement agreeChbx;

@FindBy(id="SubmitButton")
    WebElement submitBtn;

//Initializing the Page Objects:
    public RegistrationPage(){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

//Registration Page Actions
public boolean validateMaleRadioBtn(){
    return maleRadioBtn.isSelected();
}

public boolean validateUnspecifiedRadioBtn(){
    return unspecifiedRadioBtn.isSelected();
}

public void clickAgree(){
    agreeChbx.click();
}

public boolean validateSubmitBtn(){
    return submitBtn.isEnabled();
}
}


public class RegistrationPageTest extends TestBase{

HomePage homePage;
RegistrationPage registrationPage;

public RegistrationPageTest() {
    super();
}


@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    initialization();
    homePage = new HomePage();
    homePage.clickSignUp();
    registrationPage = new RegistrationPage();      
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void maleChbxTest() {
    boolean flag = registrationPage.validateMaleRadioBtn();
    Assert.assertFalse(flag);
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void unspecifiedRadioBtnTest() {
    boolean state = registrationPage.validateUnspecifiedRadioBtn();
    Assert.assertTrue(state);
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
}




java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:96)
at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:776)
at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:44)
at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:54)
at com.qa.testcases.RegistrationPageTest.unspecifiedRadioBtnTest(RegistrationPageTest.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Your `unspecifiedRadioBtn` is found by `xpath="//label..."`. Radio button is normally an `input`. Show us your DOM, maybe we can help.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply.  My apologies if I'm being stupid here.  I have some sense of the DOM, but not completely.   <label xpath="1"><input type="radio" name="2c589683e49f4d9cbf7ce68a842dc363" value="" checked="checked"> (unspecified)</label>.  I used the Rel XPath suggested by CroPath.   For reference, I'm practicing on https://www.beeradvocate.com/community/register/.

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional information. In order to get better answers here, consider taking the [tour] and especially reading through [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You should seek out some tutorials on XPath, as this is not the ideal place to learn a skill.

For your specific case, you could use one of the following XPaths:

- `//label[contains(text(), 'unspecified')]/input` this will select the `input` tag under the `label` which must contain the text "unspecified".
- `//input[@type='radio'][3]` this will select the third radio button
- `//input[@value='']` this will select the input that has a blank value (the other two have different values)

There are probably other options.

Comment: Again, I appreciate your time for the reply.  I have been practicing XPath (beyond relying on CroPath), but certainly this tells me I have more to learn.